# Select list set default value does not work

Tags: 8, forms

I have referenced filed, which works like select list, I want first value be always default value in content edit page. Now N/A is always selected.

```
function theme_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  $form['field_my_name']['und']['#default_value'] = 1;
}
```

This is my code, but it does not work

Answer (score 1):

To set the default value of field change the default value inside the widget like the following :

```
 $form['field_my_name']['widget']['#default_value'] = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but it does not work too (

Comment: your field has multiple values ?

Comment: No, It is select list and can have only one value.

Comment: ok can you dump `$form['field_my_name']['widget']` and see if the `'#default_value'` present or inside  `0` ?

Comment: try with  `$form['field_my_name']['widget'][0]['#default_value'] = 1; ` ?

Comment: Again no results (

Comment: can you post dump of `$form['field_my_name']['widget']` ?